# Magento unable to log into administrator panel

Tags: authentication, admin, session-cookies, magento-1.7

I feel really dumb asking this, as I have dealt with this problem many times...  However I am unable to solve this.

I attempt to log into the Magento backend, and I get `Invalid Username or Password`.

Now BEFORE anyone jumps in to get easy points for an answer ...  I HAVE tried the four most common things:

1) in local.xml make sure sessions is set to db and not files

2) Used SQL query to reset password in MD5 format, and check database to ensure said user was updated

3) Removed the cookie domain from core_config table

4) Last but not least did the terrible...  commented the cookie information out of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` specifically these lines:

```
 //$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
 //$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
 //$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
```

I have cleared cache multiple times, both /var/cache and ZEND cache, including directly after each change.

One thing to mention -- And I am pretty sure that this has something to do with it, I'm just unsure how, but I am using `mysite.com/test` as the staging area while I get the site working, and will move it to `mysite.com` once all the bugs are worked out.  My `base_url` is set to `mysite.com/test` in the database, however.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and after trying all of the things you mentioned that you tried it had turned out i was out of space.  I think this could have something to do with magento being unable to create additional files and so not letting you in.

Try checking usage/disk space/bandwidth and make sure everything is in order.

I also noticed i was able to log in with a Opera first, then i modified the cookie expiration time at:

System -> Configuration -> Session cookie management -> Cookie lifetime